# Shortest combination of overlapping strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to complete this [programming challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/46km7n/20160219_challenge_254_hard_dna_shotgun_sequencing/) in javascript, but I'm not getting the same desired result.

---

> Description
>
> DNA sequences are made up of a 4 character alphabet - A, C, T or G, that describe the nucleotide bases in a gene sequence. To ascertain the sequence of DNA, scientists use chemical methods to identify the component nucleotides in a method called DNA sequencing. DNA shotgun sequencing is a method whereby DNA subsequences of the same larger sequence are produced at massive parallel scale by DNA sequencing methods, and the overlap between segments is used to reconstruct the input gene. This is a fast and accurate method, and is dropping in price. Shotgun sequencing was used to perform the first entire sequence of a human's DNA, for example. For additional background information, see Wikipedia on shotgun sequencing.
>
> You're working in a DNA laboratory and you have to reconstruct a gene's sequence from a series of fragments!
>
> Formal Input Description
>
> You'll be given a series of DNA sequence fragments, which include overlaps with neighbor sequences, but not in any specific order - it's random. Your job is to read in the fragments and reconstruct the input DNA sequence that lead to the fragments.
>
> Formal Output Description
>
> Your program should emit the DNA sequence it calculated.
>
> Sample Input
>
> You'll be given the DNA sequence of one of the strands of DNA (e.g. no complementarity calculations or inferences required) using the DNA alphabet of "a,t,c,g". Assume no read errors, also. Example:
>
> ```
> tgca
> taggcta
> gtcatgcttaggcta
> agcatgctgcag
> tcatgct
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> Your program should emit the shortest DNA sequence that would contain the above fragments. Example:
>
> ```
> agcatgctgcagtcatgcttaggcta
> ```

---

I'm mostly relying on underscore to do the hard work, with a reduce function to construct the resulting 'super string', but I can't figure out what is wrong with my algorithm.

Here is the code (I've used a reverse function rather than get my head round slice the string from the end backwards):

```
String.prototype.reverse = function reverse_01 () {
  var o = '';
    var s = this;
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];

  return o;
}

var sequenceString = `tgca
    taggcta
    gtcatgcttaggcta
    agcatgctgcag
    tcatgct`

var seqs = _.chain(sequenceString.split('\n'))
  .map(function(seq) {
    return seq.trim()
  })
  .sortBy('length').reverse()
  .reduce(function(memo, seqr) {
    var candidate = seqr;
    var len = _.size(seqr)-1;
    var index = _.indexOf(memo, candidate);
    console.log('before: memo = '+memo)
    console.log('before: el = ' +seqr)
    if (!_.contains(memo, candidate)) {
      while (len > 0) {
        var leftCan = candidate.slice(0, len);
        var rightCan = candidate.reverse().slice(0, len).reverse();
        console.log('start candidate: '+leftCan)
        console.log('end candidate: '+rightCan)
        console.log('memo: '+memo)
        if (memo.startsWith(leftCan)) {
          memo = rightCan + memo;
          break;
        } else if (memo.endsWith(rightCan)) {
          memo = memo + leftCan;
          break;
        }
        len = len - 1;
      }
    }
    console.log('after: memo = '+memo)
    return memo;
  }).value()

console.log(seqs+'\n'+'agcatgctgcagtcatgcttaggcta')
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8857pt0/2/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the entire challenge question?

Comment: Sorry, the challenge info is a little too vague for me or figure out quickly.  Maybe try deleting and reposting so everyone has a chance to look at the whole thing.

Comment: Your attempt has a complexity linear with the number of fragments, but I strongly doubt you can solve this kind of problem with a linear program. Consider that there may be several solutions for example: tgca and gcatg can give tgcatg and gcatgca (the challenge says: keep the shortest). There may be nothing wrong with your code, but you need to think of another algorithm (I can think of a clean and pretty solution with recursion, not necessarily super-fast though).